# Getting price data from YahooFinance causes: AttributeError 'nonetype' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, error-handling, yahoo-finance, nonetype

I have a loop (runs about 200 times) to get previous close price from YahooFinance. This loop stops randomly at a point with the following error message:

```
WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.
[...]
AttributeError 'nonetype' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Each time I run the script it stops at a different point. This is the script:

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
import csv

with open('instruments.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    instruments = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, quotechar='"')
    for instrument in instruments:
        symbol = instrument[0]
        yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(symbol)
        price = yahoo_financials.get_prev_close_price()
```

Comment: Does it happen when you add some sleep between the Yahoo requests?

Comment: I tried it but it is the same result. I tried it with 2sec, 5sec, 10 sec but still no change.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: instead of looping over every symbol and request the price you can create a list of symbols and give this list to the YahooFincials api and then do the request. Seems like the package can handle this perfectly although it takes some time. 
Here is an excerpt from the [doc](https://github.com/JECSand/yahoofinancials):

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
tech_stocks = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'INTC']
yahoo_financials_tech = YahooFinancials(tech_stocks)
tech_stock_price_data = yahoo_financials_tech.get_prev_close_price()
```